# Throw/Catch Exception in Groovy

Tags: groovy, spock

I am new to Groovy and trying to implement Spock framework in my application.
Here is my test code:

```
def "Test class with mock object"()  {

        setup:
        SomeObject sp = Mock()
        test= TestClass()

        when:
        System.out.println('comes here');
        push.exec(sp)

        then:
        sp.length == 1

    }
```

Here `TestClass` is throwing some exception which I have to catch in test method or throw it again. I tried

```
try {

  push.exec(sp)
} catch (Exception e) {

}
```

But still getting

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: test.spock.TestClassTest.TestClass() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), use(java.util.List, groovy.lang.Closure), use(java.lang.Class, groovy.lang.Closure), dump(), with(groovy.lang.Closure), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `test = TestClass()`, it should be `test = new TestClass()`. To test for an expected exception, use `Specification.thrown` instead of try-catch. See Spock's [Javadoc](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/javadoc/latest/spock/lang/Specification.html#thrown%28java.lang.Class%29) for an example.

Comment: Javadoc link is broken

Answer (score 5):

That's the correct way to handle exceptions in Spock:

```
def "Test class with mock object"()  {

    setup:
    SomeObject sp = Mock()
    test= TestClass()

    when:
    System.out.println('comes here');
    push.exec(sp)

    then:
    thrown(YourExceptionClass)
    sp.length == 1

}
```

or if you want to check some data in your exception you may use something like:

```
    then:
    YourExceptionClass e = thrown()
    e.cause == null
```