# Testing for a exception that is thrown in a java function to be captured in a spock unit test

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, gradle, spock

```
java version 1.7.0_75  
Gradle 2.2
Groovy: 2.3.6
spock-core.1.0
```

Hello,

I have a java function that I am trying to unit test using spock framework. The function will throw an exception if something there is a `NullPointerException`.

```
 public void disconnect() throws NullPointerException {
        if(mClientConnection == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("mClientConnection has an invalid reference");
        }

        if(mClientConnection.isConnected()) {
            mClientConnection.disconnect();
        }

        mClientConnection = null;
    }
```

I am trying to test that condition in my spock unit test. Below I am trying to capture if the NullPointerException is thrown or not. However, this is not correct as I get the following error:

```
'expect' is not allowed here; instead, use one of: [and, then] @ thrown() != nullPointerException
```

Here is my unit test spock test:

```
def 'Disconnect from a connected client'() {
    setup:
    SmackClient smackClient = SmackClient.getSmackClient()

    when: /* Disconnect from a existing connection */
    smackClient.disconnect()

    expect: 
    thrown() != nullPointerException
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: possible duplicate of [Throw/Catch Exception in Groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15909716/throw-catch-exception-in-groovy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proper word to follow `when` is `then` (as the error message states).

Also its `thrown(NullPointerException)`.

see the docs:

> [Exception Conditions](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/spock_primer.html)
>
> Exception conditions are used to describe that a when block should throw an exception. They are defined using the thrown() method, passing along the expected exception type. For example, to describe that popping from an empty stack should throw an EmptyStackException, you could write the following:
>
> ```
> when:
> stack.pop()
>
> then:
> thrown(EmptyStackException)
> stack.empty
> ```